# Different method of normalize values in image processing

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I was trying to create a neural network to distinguish forest from other land in satellite images.

I started analysing the images but I'm not sure not sure how to normalize the pixel values.

I thought to divide each pixel value by 255 but in an example made by bnsreenu i found this part

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()

root_directory = 'Semantic segmentation dataset/'

patch_size = 256

#Read images from repsective 'images' subdirectory
#As all images are of ddifferent size we have 2 options, either resize or crop
#But, some images are too large and some small. Resizing will change the size of real objects.
#Therefore, we will crop them to a nearest size divisible by 256 and then 
#divide all images into patches of 256x256x3. 
image_dataset = []  
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root_directory):
    #print(path)  
    dirname = path.split(os.path.sep)[-1]
    if dirname == 'images':   #Find all 'images' directories
        images = os.listdir(path)  #List of all image names in this subdirectory
        for i, image_name in enumerate(images):  
            if image_name.endswith(".jpg"):   #Only read jpg images...
               
                image = cv2.imread(path+"/"+image_name, 1)  #Read each image as BGR
                SIZE_X = (image.shape[1]//patch_size)*patch_size #Nearest size divisible by our patch size
                SIZE_Y = (image.shape[0]//patch_size)*patch_size #Nearest size divisible by our patch size
                image = Image.fromarray(image)
                image = image.crop((0 ,0, SIZE_X, SIZE_Y))  #Crop from top left corner
                #image = image.resize((SIZE_X, SIZE_Y))  #Try not to resize for semantic segmentation
                image = np.array(image)             
       
                #Extract patches from each image
                print("Now patchifying image:", path+"/"+image_name)
                patches_img = patchify(image, (patch_size, patch_size, 3), step=patch_size)  #Step=256 for 256 patches means no overlap
        
                for i in range(patches_img.shape[0]):
                    for j in range(patches_img.shape[1]):
                        
                        single_patch_img = patches_img[i,j,:,:]
                        
                        #Use minmaxscaler instead of just dividing by 255. 
                        single_patch_img = scaler.fit_transform(single_patch_img.reshape(-1, single_patch_img.shape[-1])).reshape(single_patch_img.shape)
                        
                        #single_patch_img = (single_patch_img.astype('float32')) / 255. 
                        single_patch_img = single_patch_img[0] #Drop the extra unecessary dimension that patchify adds.                               
                        image_dataset.append(single_patch_img)
```

In this example he uses a minmaxscaler that give different values compared as diving by 255.
What method is better or more adapt to the situation?
I'll leave the link below:

[github repo with full code](https://github.com/bnsreenu/python_for_microscopists/blob/master/228_semantic_segmentation_of_aerial_imagery_using_unet/228_training_aerial_imagery.py)

Comment: Another possible option (apart from resize and crop) is to fill small samples out to a standard larger frame by reflecting the contents outwards from the edges. You might also need to generate copies of target objects in training phase and then ignore ghost objects from reflected zones in usage. On scaling, you could easily introduce unreal artifacts by scaling from min value to max value, especially in images that have little variation in one of the colours, but perhaps in real images it works enough of the time to be useful.

Comment: and what about the minmaxscaler? Is it better to use that or simply dividing every pixel by 255 In your opinion?

Comment: MinMaxScaler is literally the same as dividing by 255 (think about why).

Comment: But doesn't the scaler get the maximum and the minimum value of the data? For example if my maximum bit has a value of 150 doesn't it divide by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MinMaxScaler indeed may produce different values rather than simple division by 255 (In case, there are no pixels with intensities 0 or 255). As [official scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) documentation say, it performs the following transformation:

```
X_std = (X - X.min(axis=0)) / (X.max(axis=0) - X.min(axis=0))
X_scaled = X_std * (max - min) + min
```

where max, min - desirable values.

Therefore, normalalizing data is rather data (and probably model) specific operation. The division by 255 is a most common way to do so and for the many cases it's enough to do. As you use neural network, you can check answers to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211436/why-normalize-images-by-subtracting-datasets-image-mean-instead-of-the-current) to learn more about why you should normilize/center your data.